# Klein's 4 subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I have just started learning about group theory. And, I learnt about The Klein's 4 group. I tried proving that two distinct Klein's 4 subgroup of a group intersect only at Identity. But I can't. So please help me.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you want to prove that if $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ are distinct Klein $4$-subgroups of a group $G$ then $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ have trivial intersection.

This is not true.  Take $G = S_{6}$, and
$$V_{1} = \langle (1,2), (3,4)\rangle
\;\;\text{and}\;\;
V_{2} = \langle (3,4), (5,6)\rangle.$$
Then $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ are both subgroups of $G = S_{6}$, each isomorphic to the Klein $4$-group, but $V_{1}\cap V_{2} = \langle (3,4)\rangle\neq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Or an even smaller example - $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Take de Klein 4-groups $V=\{(0,0,0), (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0)\}$ and $W=\{(0,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,1)\}$, then $V \cap W=\{(0,0,0), (0,1,0)\}$.

Comment: You missed some "/" in the first line.